# What is the distance metric in dynamic time warping?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, speech-recognition, speech-processing

I am reading the lecture slides from this site http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/CS-498-DAF-P/Lecture%2018%20-%20Time%20series,%20DTW.pdf

In slide 24, the lecture suggest using metric of the following

```
d(i, j) = ||f(i) - f(j)||

select top frequency in i and top frequency in j, 
    find the Euclidean distance between the two
```

I am not exactly sure what do they mean by Euclidean distance between the two.

Did they meant to have top n frequency sorted in order and match the order for subtraction and find the euclidean distance?

For example

```
f1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

f2 = [1, 100, 200 ,300]


d(1,2) = |1-1| + |100-2| + |200-3| + |300-4|
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euclidean distance between two vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ is $\mathrm d(\mathbf a, \mathbf b) \equiv \sqrt {\sum_i (a_i - b_i)^2}$

In your example you forgot to square the differences. Remember the way you calculate hypotenuse of a triangle; it's the same idea.

Comment: Thanks, so I just want to confirm that the metric is using the top n frequency and minus each other according to the order? So you wouldn't have second highest subtract the fourth highest frequency?

Comment: Where does it say that on [slide 24](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/CS-498-DAF-PS/Lecture%2018%20-%20Time%20series,%20DTW.pdf#page=24)? The only thing I see is "Given our robust feature we can use a simple
measure like Euclidean distance".

Comment: exactly, so because it wasn't elucidated in the document, I was confused on what to compare, for example given a's top frequency is [a1, a2] and b's top frequency is [b1, b2], in general |a1-b1|_2 + |a2-b2|_2 is not the same as |a1-b2|_2  + |a2-b1|_2

Comment: So where did you get the idea that you were supposed to do that?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what else to do, is there other way of pairing $a_i$ to $b_i$?

Comment: I would suggest following a different source. Presentation notes are not a substitute for a textbook and DTW is a well known technique.

Comment: Can you recommend some resource? Most of the source I found is very vague, I cannot really find any example walk through for the distance metric.

Comment: There are worked examples [here](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-M/slides/04.5.TimeSeries2.pdf) and [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~lxiong/cs730_s13/share/slides/searching_sigkdd2012_DTW.pdf). I apologize for not having the time for a proper explanation.